# Alternative to calculated field when working with a data model

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-platform

I have an Excel with a connection to a PowerBI data model (which i cannot edit)
I want to create a table from the data model but need to add a custom (calculated) field.
This is not possible nor is it possible to add a field to the data model itself (restricted acces).

Is there a way to create the custom field? The field Autonome Afzet needs to be filled with Afzet(stuks) when Autonome omzet > 1

[image: Example]